# Nontrivial integer solutions of $ a^3+b^3=c^3+d^3$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic, pythagorean-triples, fermat-numbers

How can we obtain a set of nontrivial solutions of

> $$
> a^3+b^3=c^3+d^3,
> $$
>   for $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{Z}$
>   where $(a,b)\neq (c,d)$ and $(a,b)\neq (d,c)$.

- Say in the range that $|a|,|b|,|c|,|d| \in [0,30]$, whose absolute values small or eqaul to 30?
- How many simple but nontrivial solutions are there around this range?

The simple form the solutions are the better.

Thank you!

p.s. When $d=0$, we know it is impossible due to the [Fermat's Last Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem).

Comment: Here's one such set: $\{(1,12,9,10),(2,16,9,15)\}$

Comment: Have a look at the paper [Characterizing
the Sum of Two Cubes](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL6/Broughan/broughan25.pdf).

Comment: Could you include your own efforts in trying to answer these *two* questions?  As it is, it looks like an exercise or assigned problem and that you're expecting us to answer it entirely for you.

Comment: p.s. It is summer. It is not an exercise or assigned problem. It is just something coming out for fun for the summer.

Comment: See Euler's general solution [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_sum_of_powers_conjecture#Background) for example.

Comment: One thing I knew is that Plato's number actually works if you want to see my efforts:
$$
3^3 + 4^3 = (-5)^3 + 6^3=91,
$$
also formulating a question may be an effort if you contemplate something bigger than the question seems to be. Thanks for all other's useful answers! These are very beneficial (much more than simply complaining or voting down).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107570/generalization-of-pythagorean-triples/721310#721310

Comment: A brute-force computational search isn't hard, but also not particularly enlightening.  The results of such a search are at https://oeis.org/A051347

Comment: This is just a cute coincidence $3^3+4^3+5^3=6^3$ but you knew that, right?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to give a partial answer by mimicking Kummer's approach to the first case of FLT. As in your other related question, let us introduce $\omega$ = a primitive 3rd root of unity, the quadratic field $\mathbf Q(\omega)$, its ring of integers $\mathbf Z[\omega]$. We intend to solve the diophantine equation $a^3+b^3=c^3+d^3$ under the *additional hypothesis* that $3\nmid a+b$ (or equivalently $3\nmid c+d$, by Fermat's little theorem). For simplification, let us concentrate on *primitive* solutions, i.e. suppose that $a, b$ are coprime (and similarly $c,d$ ).To exploit the decomposition $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a+b\omega)(a+b\omega^2)$, we must recall that $\mathbf Z[\omega]$ is a principal ideal ring, whose group of units coincides with its group of roots of unity, generated by $\pm \omega$.

***Lemma***: Under our hypotheses, for $m\neq  n$ mod 3, the factors $(a+b\omega^m)$ and $(a+b\omega^n)$ are coprime in $\mathbf Z[\omega]$. ***Proof***: Since $\mathbf Z[\omega]$ is principal, let us apply Bézout's theorem by showing that  the ideal $J$ generated by our two elements contains $1$. Because $\omega^k$ is a primitive 3rd root of unity whenever $k \neq 0$ mod 3, the quotient $\epsilon_k=\frac {1-\omega^k}{1-\omega}$ is a unit. But $(a+b\omega^m)-(a+b\omega^n)=\omega^m(1-\omega^{n-m})b=\epsilon_{n-m}\omega^m(1-\omega)b$ , and similarly $(a+b\omega^m)\omega^n-(a+b\omega^n)\omega^m=-\omega^m(1-\omega^{n-m})a= - \epsilon_{n-m}\omega^m(1-\omega)a$, hence $(1-\omega)b$ and $ (1-\omega)a \in J$. Since $a,b$ are coprime in $\mathbf Z$,  Bézout asserts the existence of $u,v \in \mathbf Z$ s.t. $ua+vb=1$, hence $(1-\omega)ua+(1-\omega)vb=(1-\omega) \in J$, hence also $3\in J$. Moreover, $a+b=(a+b\omega^m)+(1-\omega^m)b=(a+b\omega^ma+b\omega^m)+(1-\omega)\epsilon_mb$, so that $a+b \in J$. Finally, our additional hypothesis implies the existence of $s,t\in \mathbf Z$ s.t. 
$(a+b)s+3t=1$, hence $1\in J$. OUF

EDIT : Any rational prime $p\neq 3$ is unramified in $\mathbf Q(\omega)$. Let $\delta$= gcd $(a+b,c+d)$ and $N$= the norm of $\mathbf Q (\omega)/\mathbf Q$ . Our additional hypothesis and the lemma then imply that  $\frac {a+b}{\delta}=\pm N(c+d\omega)=\pm (c^2+d^2-cd)=\pm ((c+d)^2-3cd)$, and similarly $\frac {c+d}{\delta}=\pm ((a+b)^2-3ab)$. Besides, since $c,d$ are the roots of the quadratic equation $x^2-(c+d)x+cd=0$, the discriminant $\Delta=(c+d)^2-4cd=((c+d)^2-3cd)-cd$ is necessarily a perfect square (=square of an integer), and similarly $((a+b)^2-3ab)-cd$ is a perfect square. Summarizing, $\pm\frac{a+b}{\delta}-cd$ and $\pm\frac{c+d}{\delta}-ab$ must be perfect squares.

EDIT 2: I made a mistake again ! $(a+b\omega)$ and $(c+d\omega)$ could have a common factor. This seems to be a dead end.

Comment: thanks for your nice efforts - +1.

Comment: Unfortunately my conclusion was too hasty. There is an obvious contradiction with the Plato number. I think I made an error in the derivation of the equality  $a+b=\pm(c+d)$. I'll think about it more thoroughly and edit it if possible.

Comment: thanks for letting us know -

Comment: I edited my first answer. What I get now is a *necessary* condition, which can be checked numerically in a limited range of absolute values of the variables.

Comment: I made a mistake again ! $a+b\omega$ and $c+d\omega$ could have a common factor. This seems to be a dead end.