# Proof of $a^3 - b^3 = c^3 + d^3$, where $a,b,c,d$ all rational?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Reading Wikipedia article on Diophantus, it says in a book that survived that he makes reference to a lost book called Porisms and the theorem stated in the title: the difference between the cubes of any 2 rationals can be expressed as the sum of the cubes of 2 rationals. Anyone point me to this proof?

Comment: Take $c=a$ and $d=-b$?  Were there any restrictions you left off?

Comment: Diophantus would not have considered negative numbers.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107570/generalization-of-pythagorean-triples/721310#721310

Answer (score 8):

$c=\frac{a(a^3-2b^3)}{a^3+b^3},d=\frac{b(2a^3-b^3)}{a^3+b^3}$ gives a solution which I believe is due to Vieta.

Answer (score 2):

The question asks about a theorem of Diophantus.

L. E. Dickson, *History of the Theory of Numbers*, Volume II, Chapter XXI, section "Two equal sums of two cubes", pp. $550$-$561$ begins on page $550$ with

> $\quad$ Diophantus, V, $19$, mentions without details the theorem in the *Porisms*
> that the difference of two cubes is always a sum of two cubes (cf. p. $607$).

> $\quad$ F. Vieta$^{38}$ required two cubes whose sum equals the difference
> $\,B^3-D^3\,$ of two given cubes $\,(B>D).\,$ Call $\,B-A\,$ the
> side of the first required cube and $\,B^2A/D-D\,$ the side of
> the second. Thus $\,(B^3+D^3)A=3D^3B\,$ and hence
> $$(1)\qquad x^3+y^3=B^3-D^3,\quad x=\frac{B(B^3-2D^3)}{B^3+D^3},
> \quad y=\frac{D(2B^3-D^3)}{B^3+D^3}. $$

Following Vieta, let $\,b>a>0\,$ be two positive integers. Define

$$
x := b(b^3-2a^3),\;\; y := a(2b^3-a^3),\\
c := x/(b^3+a^3),\;\; d := y/(b^3+a^3). \tag{1} $$

The algebraic equality
$$c^3 + d^3 = b^3 - a^3  \tag{2} $$

can be verified using elementary algebra by substituting
the definitions from equation $(1)$ and expanding
$\,c^3+d^3.\,$ Here$\,c>0\,$ requires that $\,b^3>2a^3\,$
which implies also $\,d>0.\,$

The two given numbers $\,a,b\,$ were arbitrary and equation
$(2)$ holds which proves that the difference of two cubes is
also the sum of two cubes. This answers the question

> Anyone point me to this proof?

by giving a proof as requested.